# I've distributed a total of 400 flyers today

Tags: present-perfect

> I've distributed a total of 400 flyers today.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? I need to report the number of flyers I have distributed every day but I'm unsure if the sentence is correct

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct. What troubles you? it is a present perfect and the structure is alright!

Answer (score 2):

Generally my advice would be to use the present perfect for a sentence like this only if it's in the sense of "and continue to do so", for example if someone asks you during your lunch break:

> I've distributed a total of 400 flyers *so far* today.

If you're talking to someone over a drink in the evening once you're done with that day's work, the simple past might be more appropriate (even if you intend to do the same thing again tomorrow):

> *I distributed* a total of 400 flyers today.

That's because this *instance* of distributing flyers is complete, and happened in the past. If, though, you want to say it in terms of "this is how many I've been able to distribute each day over the course of my time working this job" (and you still have that same job), then it'd be the present perfect:

> I've distributed 400 flyers *per day* for the last two years.

And if you resigned from that job some time ago, then it would be the simple past again:

> I distributed 400 flyers per day while I was working there.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence looks correct.
See the difference,
when you say "I have", that implies that you have already done so. This is present perfect tense.

When you say "I distributed 400 flyers today".

This is past indefinite form of the sentence.

Unless you are a purist, both are correct.